# C++ "Error: no matching function for call to" with paramater std::ofstream&

Tags: c++

I am working on a C++ project and want to reference a function called printStatus in a class called Manager in a separate header file from my main function. I believe they have the same parameters, but I am getting the error: "no matching function for call to 'Manager::printStatus(std::ofstream&)'"

## Manger.h:

```
#ifndef MANAGER_H
#define MANAGER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Manager{
public:
    // Constructor
    Manager(std::string filename1, std::string filename2);
    // Function of interest
    void printStatus(std::ofstream &o);
};

#endif
```

## Driver.cpp:

```
#include "Manager.h"
using namespace std;

int main(in argc, char* argv[]){
    ofstream outputFileStream;

    // take in store and order files
    Manager manager(argv[1], argv[2]);

    // open output file
    outputFileStream.open("results.txt");

    // execute function of interest
    manager.printStatus(outputFileStream);

    // close output file
    outputFileStream.close();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I don't have function definitions for the class yet, but I am just trying to get this piece of code to compile. I am inputting a ofstream parameter into Manager::printStatus in Driver.cpp and in Manager.h I have declared printStatus to accept an ofstream parameter. I do not understand the issue.

## Compiler:

```
Driver.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
Driver.cpp:14:38: error: no matching function for call to 'Manager::printStatus(std::ofstream&)'
  manager.printStatus(outputFileStream);
                                      ^
```

Manager.h:

Comment: The error message should continue with a list of the known candidates. (The most common cause of this particular problem is that you have either forgotten to save a file, or are editing a different file from the one you're compiling.)

Comment: @InnocentBystander this hasn't been an issue with other functions. I tried giving the function a trivial definition but I still get the same error.

Comment: @InnocentBystander That should generate a link error (undefined reference).  The error the OP has is saying it can't even find a suitable declaration.

Comment: @linuxnoob & NathanOliver I stand corrected. The code you posted above compiles just fine: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/910e8eaa9d939fc6 Please check for other things.

Comment: @linuxnoob maybe post full output of the compiler. It should give more clues.

Comment: @molbdnilo The candidate is: 'void Manager::printStatus(int&)' which is confusing because I don't have type int anywhere in my code.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/LLGYLr

Comment: @linuxnoob post **full** compiler output.

Comment: Try building a demo on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org) which reproduces the error.